# Whats the difference between logistic regression and fractional response model?

Tags: regression, logistic, econometrics, quasi-likelihood, population-attributable-fraction

1. Can anyone tell me the theory behind fractional response model, how it really works?
2. I wonder if the logistic regression works only with binary variable {0,1}, why when conducting a GLM with quasibinomial family on fractional variable [0-1], it gave me same results in the estimates as the fractional response model?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the term *fractional response model* before, but assuming it is models for fractions between zero and one as response, as it is used [in this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/(SICI)1099-1255(199611)11:6%3C619::AID-JAE418%3E3.0.CO;2-1), it seems to be a term used by econometricians for logistic quasi-likelihood.

If you use R, these models are estimated simply by switching from the `binomial` family function to the `quasibinomial` family function.